# How to force Mediawiki to write an ampersand in HTML without it being encoded as &amp;

Tags: mediawiki

Automatic encoding of `&` as `&amp;` breaks expected functionality for extensions that write HTML or JS if the script/HTML text being written depends on them.

For example, if you write a script with a boolean AND conditional, the `&&` gets encoded as `&amp;&amp;` which makes no sense.

https://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Help:Formatting

Nowiki tags don't apply to this encoding. Is there an extension available that allows HTML output of plain `&`?

Comment: Interesting. The question formatting here displays & a m p; (remove the spaces) as a single &.

Comment: Request for edit/formatting help: If anyone can properly encode the & a m p ; (as a code block), can you help or flag my question for edit/reformatting?

Comment: The formatting you're looking for is the backtick, e.g. : `\`&amp;\`` displays as `&amp;`.

Comment: Are you getting this problem on a `common.js` page or simlar? Do you have a link to your wiki?

Comment: Extensions can fully control their output, and scripts can use the raw wikitext source instead of the rendered HTML output. Sounds like you are using some poorly written extension/script but without saying which one there is not much we can say to help.